# How to identify the address which deployed smart Contract in etherum

Tags: contract-deployment

If someone deployed smart Contract in the etherum to swap tokens , how to identify what is address which deployed the contract? And which is the exchange used to deploy contract? And if in single transaction tokens transferred to  multiple deposit addresses , how to check those deposit addresses belongs to whom ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the creator of the contract
[image]

Not sure about your second question, what do you exactly want to know? The addresses to which a token is sent are visible on etherscan. You can't further know who owns the address.

Comment: My second question is about to deploy contract , is it mandatory to contact exchange to deploy contract? Or without the exchange can we deploy?

Comment: No, exchange is not needed to deploy a contract, anyone can deploy a contract.